# Why Ubuntu doesn't upgrade to the latest version of GnuPG?

Tags: apt, updates, security, gnupg

Two days ago GnuPG [announced](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2013q4/000337.html) the release of a new stable version.

The new version is 1.4.16 but the repository of Ubuntu Saucy have 1.4.14.

I don't understand this because the new release cover a *critical bug* and, as you can see in the next picture, Canonical *provides* critical updates.

[image: canonical provides critical updates for GPG until 2014]

After `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get upgrade` it says there is nothing to update.

Why?

Comment: I had to wait a week for the update from Firefox 24 to 25 *(stable)* - after it is released, it probably needs to be packaged & optimized for each distribution, including Ubuntu.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken security updates patch are backported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the bug fix installed already. Version `1.4.14-1ubuntu2.1` is the update with the security fix, and it was released into the archive on December 18, 2013. You can see [GnuPG on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnupg) for more details about which version is in which series and pockets.

Comment: In fact, [it has been included](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnupg/1.4.14-1ubuntu2.1). I would have never guess looking at the numbers. It is a bit of strange and important to have in mind. Thanks!